# ajax pagination in cakephp , can't know how to use it

Tags: cakephp

how to use ajax pagination in cakephp .I'm also using search the database by the keywords also.. data only matches with keyword shoud be displayed in pagination
how to use ajax pagination in cakephp .I'm also using search the database by the keywords also.. data only matches with keyword shoud be displayed in pagination

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried it .. refer the book , ajax pagination example also there, and in paginator add condition option ... ie. `

```
$this->paginate=array((`array('condition'=>model.field )like=>%key%),limit=>10) ;
```